# Making MySQL accessible to remote IPs

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql

How do I make MySQL accessible to only certain specified IP addresses? I'd like to access the database through a remote server

Answer (score 1):

if you using linux as server you need to edit `mysqld.cnf` file for **mysql version 5.7 and above** or `my.cnf` file for **mysql version 5.6 and below** and change this line:

`bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

to:

`bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

(or you can change `0.0.0.0` to your public ip)

then restart your mysql service.

Afterwards execute this query in your database :

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'username'@'%';`

change `username` for your username, `mydb` to your database and `%` for ip address that you want allow to access, you could check the complete reference for setting config mysql and mysql query on this link :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663001/remote-connections-mysql-ubuntu#answer-15684341

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72142/how-do-i-allow-remote-mysql-access-to-all-users#answer-72157